# Top quintiles for several categorical values

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, unique

In general, I want to get the top quintile of a data frame of the distribution of one column. However, it needs to be the top quintile for every unique categorical value of another column.

I guess it has to be done in several steps, potentially with a loop. At first, I need to separate the data frames according to the unique categorical values, then only keep the top quintiles of every new data frame and then lastly rowbind the dataframes together again. 
But I have no idea how to do this.

Some sample data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:3],times = 5),
                  y = rep(1:3,each = 5))
    > dat
   x y
1  a 1
2  b 1
3  c 1
4  a 1
5  b 1
6  c 2
7  a 2
8  b 2
9  c 2
10 a 2
11 b 3
12 c 3
13 a 3
14 b 3
15 c 3
```

In Step 1 I want to create a data frame for every unique categorical value. Something like:

```
> df.a
     x y
    1  a 1
    2  a 1
    3  a 2
    4  a 2
    5  a 3
```

df.b and df.c accordingly

In the second step, I only want to  keep the top quintile of every new data frame. Something like:

Should become this:

```
> df.a=df.a[df.a$y > quantile(df.a, 0.5, na.rm = TRUE),]
     # taking the top 50% because the top quintile would not work with the sample data.
```

In the last step, I need to rbind all the new data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, your sample data makes it hard to use quintiles,  so I will slightly alter your sample data.

```
## New data
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(letters[1:3],times = 25),
                  y = sample(10, 75, replace=TRUE))
```

It is not necessary to make separate data.frames for each value of the categorical variable, in order to get the quintiles.  You can do that with `aggregate`.

```
Limits = aggregate(dat$y, list(dat$x), quantile, 0.8)
row.names(Limits) = Limits[,1]
(Limits = Limits [,-1, drop=FALSE])
    x
a 8.0
b 7.2
c 8.0
```

Now,  having the table of (top) quintiles by category,  we can just select that part of the original data that is above those quintiles (by category).

```
TopQuintile = dat[which(dat$y >= Limits[dat$x,1]), ]
```